# How to make maven to take resources from /src/test/resources instead of /src/main/resources for a dependent project?

Tags: maven, jar, resources, dependencies

I've searched the forum to find the answer to my problem, but I was unable to find it. My problem is, that:

I have two projects: ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectB uses ProjectA. In ProjectA i have two folders:
/src/main/resources and /src/test/resources.
In ProjectB i run: mvn clean install. I want, that in the test phase, classes in ProjectB use resources from /src/test/resources instead of /src/main/resources.

This is what I tried:
http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/361-maven-build-system/1349-maven-reusing-test-classes-across-multi-modules-projects.html

It is similar to my problem, but after I configured the test-jar goal for ProjectA, ProjectB still runs the tests in the way, that classes in ProjectA use properties from /src/main/resources instead of /src/test/resources.

My pom.xml in ProjectA looks like:

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In ProjectB my pom.xml looks like:

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sensano</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ProjectA</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Is there a method 
Any help would be appreciated!

Sincerely,
Mateusz Moroz

Comment: What does the filtering tag do in your pom ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `src/main/resources` are packed to the jar file named `ProjectA.jar` as the following structure

```
ProjectA.jar
|`-com
|  `-sensano
|    `-foo
`-[the resource form src/main/resources]
```

Sadly the `src/test/resources` are also packed to the jar file named `ProjectA-tests.jar` as the following structure as well.

```
ProjectA-tests.jar
|`-com
|  `-sensano
|    `-foo
`-[the resource form src/test/resources]
```

If the resource name that you require are the same name for both from `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`. There may be some class loader trouble. IMHO, the nearest wins.

Since you put the `ProjectA` before the `ProjectA-tests`, then may be the root cause that the `ProjectB` will use the `src/main/resources` from `ProjectA` since it is nearest.

Please try to swap by putting the `ProjectA-tests` before the `ProjectA` as the following: -

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sensano</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sensano</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The nearest will be the `ProjectA-tests`, and `ProjectB` should use the `src/test/resources` instead.

I hope this may help.